# How can I change my code to be able to calculate different urls instead of the current page

Tags: javascript, performance, url, page-load-time

I'm trying to calculate the load time and page size of different URLs/Pages similar to the developer tools performance tab but in javascript. But the current code only calculates its current page instead of a different URL. Is there any way for me to do this because with my research I have no luck.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<script type="text/javascript">

var start = new Date().getTime();
function onLoad() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var latency = now - start;
  alert("page loading time: " + latency+"\n"+"Start time:"+start+"\n"+"End time:"+now);
  alert("Load_size:"+document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].outerHTML.length + "KB");
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
<!- Main page body goes from here. -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you provide a different url? This code will be only executed in this page.

Answer (score 1):

It will not be possible to read the runtime parameters of a page outside the page your javascript is running on.

Part of the security model is to avoid being able to inspect the runtime of other pages.  This is called the "sandbox".  You'll need to build a plugin that breaks the sandbox to inspect the domLoad / domReady and other performance events.

Good news though, you probably have one built in!  The console for modern browsers shows all those events in the timeline tab.

If you're trying to make a service that attempts to evaluate the runtime of other pages, you'll need to load those in a virtual web browser on the server and interpret the results using selenium or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to calculate the load time of a page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function() {
                 console.log("Time until DOMready: ", Date.now()-timerStart);
             });
             $(window).load(function() {
                 console.log("Time until everything loaded: ", Date.now()-timerStart);
             });
        </script>
```

edit: this will only work on pages where this JS code will run, so if you cant insert code onto the page you wont be able to run it.